# How to feed an rxjs observer

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

everyone seems to find observers easy but i find them extremely difficult.
I need to create an observable then feed a number to it when a button is pressed, in all the examples that i found they define the content of the observable in the constructor but i need to feed it after is created.
Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: That only works inside the constructor of the observable, if i create one i cant do that

Comment: You are looking for a Subject, which is both observer and observable. You create it with `const subject = new Subject()`, then subscribe in one place with `subject.subscribe()`, and feed it in another place with `subject.next(someValue)`.

Comment: whoops - Eric is correct then.

Comment: Not quite - the syntax to feed is `subject.onNext(someValue)`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const { Subject, fromEvent } = rxjs;

const number$ = new Subject();

fromEvent(document.getElementById('button'), 'click').subscribe(() => {
  number$.next(Math.random() * 10);
});

number$.subscribe(number => {
  document.getElementById('output').innerText = number;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click for random number</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: nice sample, thanks you for sharing. You can also switch your eventListener to `fromEvent` from rxjs

Comment: Good call, seeing we are demonstrating rxjs I changed the event handler to use fromEvent.